# How to achieve query in Linq without null value?

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I'm struggling in trying to understand if I'm doing right with this Linq query. Unfortunately I'm newbie and I still have a lot of problem using the lambda expressions.

`m_ItemList` contains a list of different `GameObject`:

- `Fruit` objects

  - `bool Value;`
- `Cars` objects

  - `bool Bought;`
- Others

These objects have a different script behavior and I just want to isolate these who has the script `Cars` and retrieve which has the `bool` var on `true`. This is the query I've created firstly.

```
itemBought = m_ItemList.Where(x => x.GetComponent<Cars>().Bought).ToList();
```

Obviously this gave me an Exception's issue, since not everyone has the `Cars` script component attached.

Therefore I found the solution:

```
itemBought = m_ItemList.Where(x => x.GetComponent<Cars>()).Where(x => x.GetComponent<Cars>().Bought).ToList();
```

This works fine but it's very bad to see and I'm not even sure it's the best way to achieve it (maybe also bad in performances).

Any help?

Comment: I don't see how `Where(x => x.GetComponent<Cars>())` could work since `GetComponent` does not return a `bool` which is required by `Where`.

Comment: @juharr I suppose because it returns if the object actually has the component attached. But I'm not that sure about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetComponent` is relatively expensive operation so I would try to only call it once per object. So, select into the results of `GetComponent`, filter out the nulls and non-nulls with false `Bought` values:

```
itemBought = m_ItemList.Select(x => x.GetComponent<Cars>())
        .Where(c => c != null && c.Bought == true)
        .ToList();
```

This works if you can make `itemBought` of type `List<Cars>` or `List<MonoBehaviour>` or something else like that, and avoids needing to use `GetComponent<Cars>` in later lines

Comment: Thanks @Ruzihm I tried but it gives me this error: ```Cannot implicitly convert type 'List<bool>' to 'List<GameObject>'```

Comment: You need `.Where(c => c != null && c.Bought).ToList()`

Comment: Thanks Tim! @Six91 See the edit to this answer

Comment: @Six91: since i never used Unity but i'm interested in the answer, this does not work, does it? `.Where(c => c?.Bought == true)`. I guess not since those unity objects return `true` if you compare with `==null` even if they are actually not null but destroyed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ```c?.Bought``` doesn't work since there's difference between ```bool``` and ```bool?``` operators

Comment: @Six91: thats why i have said `c?.Bought == true` :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry, you're right. I read the question very fast and I didn't notice it. Yeah it actually works, I just tried it and confirmed :)

Comment: @Six91: i would not use my version anyway, stay with what Ruzihm has posted since unity gameobjects dont behave like normal C# objects. https://forum.unity.com/threads/simple-question-about-null-conditional-operator.734864/#post-4900244

Comment: @Ruzihm: Why you changed it to use `c?.Bought == true`? Thats risky and will not work under [certain circumstances](https://forum.unity.com/threads/simple-question-about-null-conditional-operator.734864/#post-4900244)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ah, true.

Comment: Actually you can make it a bit shorter and write `Where(c => c && c.Bought)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Quite similar to [Ruzihm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67217599/7111561) and actually pretty close to what you tried originally using only `Where` and [`TryGetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.TryGetComponent.html)

```
itemBought = m_ItemList.Where(item => item.TryGetComponent<Cars>(out var car) && car.Bought).ToList();
```

The `TryGetComponent` already contains the null check since it returns already `false` if the component was not found on the object.

Comment: Ooh, very nice. I forgot about `TryGetComponent`